# SQL Inner Join query returns no results

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm refactoring a Java program written by someone else a couple of years ago, can't get in contact with them to find out anything about the SQL / database, but this query is not working (not returning any results when having two queries separately does). I know it's annoying to ask without more info, but I haven't really got much choice at the moment.

```
"SELECT " + CLMHDR + ".POLBRC, "
+ CLMHDR + ".POLTYC, " + CLMHDR + ".POLNOC," + CLMHDR + ".CLTKYC, " 
+ POLHDR + ".INCPTP FROM "+ CLMHDR + 
"INNER JOIN " + POLHDR + " ON " + CLMHDR + ".CLTKYC = " + POLHDR+ ".CLTKYP" 
+ " WHERE POLNOC = "+ polnocSearch
+ " AND POLBRC = '" + polbrcSearch + "'"
+ " AND POLTYC = '" + poltycSearch + "'"
+ " AND DATRPC <= " + claimDate
+ " GROUP BY POLBRC, POLTYC, POLNOC, CLTKYC"
```

The tables CMLHDR and POLHDR do contain the columns it is referencing, and CLTKYC and CLTKYP are keys in each table. Sorry about the horrible names, we're stuck with RPG as well.

Edit:
What does work is this:

```
"SELECT POLBRC, POLTYC, POLNOC, CLTKYC FROM "+ CLMHDR
+ " WHERE POLNOC = "+ polnocSearch
+ " AND POLBRC = '" + polbrcSeach + "'"
+ " AND POLTYC = '" + poltycSearch + "'"
+ " AND DATRPC <= " + claimDate
+ " GROUP BY POLBRC, POLTYC, POLNOC, CLTKYC"
```

followed by this:

```
"SELECT INCPTP, TRMTHP FROM "+ POLHDR   + " WHERE POLNOP = "+ polnocSearch
+ " AND POLBRP = '"+ polbrcSearch+ "' AND POLTYP = '"+ poltycSearch + "'"
```

but I'd really prefer all the data to be returned at once.

Comment: This code look wide open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: First print the actual sql statement and see if there is anything wrong

Comment: Try the statement while narrowing the WHERE-clause. It might truly return no results. If it does not throw an error, there are no results. If it does throw, care to share?

Comment: Found an error message: INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.ibm.as400.access.MRI_en.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `inner join` problem, you have an issue with the `group by`.  It should have `INCPTP`.  In any database except for MySQL, this will generate an error.

By the way, it would be easier to answer your question if it included two things:

1. The database engine you are using
2. The resulting query string with the values filled in

Comment: Ah, adding that worked. Thanks, I didn't realise group by had to include all of the selected columns.

Answer (score 3):

There is a space missing between the FROM and the INNER JOIN clause:

```
FROM "+ CLMHDR +
"INNER JOIN
```

It is should be this:

```
FROM "+ CLMHDR + 
" INNER JOIN
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll be one problem fixed, though it's still not working unfortunately.